# CalledFromWrongThreadException при установке текста в progressDialog

Tags: java, android

Код:

```
public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Post post = null;
    public static activeServer activeServerCache = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = this;
        post = new Post();        
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            ProgressDialog pd = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd = Dialoger.progressDialog(context, "Загрузка...", "Загружаю...");
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                pd.setMessage("Гружу статус бар...");
                StatusBar.InitStatusBar(context);
                pd.setMessage("Гружу настройки...");
                Voider.loadChare(context);
                if (!Voider.getNewChare()) {
                    pd.setMessage("Гружу новые настройки...");
                    Voider.setChare("update", true);
                    Voider.setChare("updateServers", true);
                    Voider.setChare("updateRoomFone", true);
                }
                pd.setMessage("Гружу информацию о сервере...");
                activeServerCache = new activeServer(context);
                if (!activeServerCache.updateVersion())
                    Toster.toster(context, "Ошибка, сервер не поддерживает сравнение совместимости...");
                pd.setMessage("Гружу данные...");//падение
                File file = new File(context, "Auth");
                post.regenPost();
                if (file.getBooleanWritable("login") && file.getBooleanWritable("pass")
                        && activeServerCache.getActivityBooleanServer()) {
                    String login = file.getString("login");
                    String pass = file.getString("pass");
                    pd.setMessage("Авторизация...");
                    post.regenPost();
                    if (!AccountVoider.Autoriz(context, login, pass, false)) {
                        Toster.toster(context, "Ошибка авторизации, данные сохранены...");
                        post.unset();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Autorizes.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UChat.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    post.unset();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Autorizes.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Лог ошибки:

> 08-24 01:49:16.966    8897-8921/ux.uchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
>        Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5288)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:974)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4166)
>               at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10437)
>               at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10392)
>               at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6467)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3719)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3577)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3552)
>               at android.app.ProgressDialog.setMessage(ProgressDialog.java:316)
>               at ux.uchat.Start$1.doInBackground(Start.java:69)
>               at ux.uchat.Start$1.doInBackground(Start.java:26)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
>   08-24 01:49:17.179    8897-8897/ux.uchat E/WindowManager﹕ Activity ux.uchat.Start has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42088568 V.E..... R......D 0,0-580,162} that was originally added here
>       android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ux.uchat.Start has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42088568 V.E..... R......D 0,0-580,162} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
>               at ux.uchat.Start$1.onPreExecute(Start.java:33)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
>               at ux.uchat.Start.onCreate(Start.java:105)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно сообщения вида pd.setMessage(""); перенести в метод onProgressUpdate(), а из doInBackground() дергать метод publishProgress(message). [Более подробно.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html). Вы не можете обращаться к элементам интерфейса не из UI потока.

Comment: Да спасибо заработало, сделал функцию @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                pd.setMessage(values[0]);
            } и достаю ее из                 publishProgress(new String[]{"Гружу статус бар"});
 вроде все работает

Answer (score 2):

Все операции с интерфейсом следует делать в основном потоке. Вот даже написано.

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

Comment: А я где делаю по вашему?, обновлю код чтобы вся активность была видна, P.S прошлый метод             pd.setMessage("Гружу информацию о сервере..."); работает...

Comment: +если заметили это в AsyncTask

Comment: Класс AsyncTask выполняет действия из метода doInBackground() в параллельном потоке, поэтому для обновления диалога, созданного в основном потоке используйте переопределенный метод onProgressUpdate()